Is there a command or keyboard shortcut to request the Copilot suggested commit message in the terminal?

I've seen the sparkle icon in the terminal for adding the suggestion, though this requires two mouse clicks which then pastes into the terminal line
git commit -m "[Copilot suggestion here...].
Is there a way to activate this via a keyboard shortcut, or a command?
E.g. if you are staging files via something like git add -p you are already using the keyboard as opposed to the mouse, so it would be a great help if there was a keyboard shortcut for requesting the commit message suggestion once all files are staged.

Thanks to @Alfred Luu's idea of using keybindings.
When you are staging commits in the integrated terminal, it's useful to have copilot suggest the commit message, allow you to make any edits, and then commit- without needing the mouse and returning the focus to the terminal for further commands like git status and git log
To add this functionality:

In VSCode open your keyboard shortcuts to add a new shortcut. You can do this by pressing f1 and then type Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON).
This will open your keybindings.json file where you can save your custom keybinds.

Inside, paste these three new keybindings:


    {
        "key": "ctrl+oem_1",
        "command" : "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "workbench.view.scm",
                "github.copilot.git.generateCommitMessage",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key" : "ctrl+oem_7",
        "command" : "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "git.commit",
                "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
            ]
        },
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+oem_7",
        "command": "runCommands",
        "args": {
            "commands": [
                "git.commit",
                "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
            ]
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }


Replace the "key" with the keyboard shortcut you want for the two behaviours.

E.g.: "key": "ctrl+m"


Save keybindings.json


How to use
My defaults are:

Ctrl+; (Keybinding #1) -> Opens the source control view on the side, and gets copilot to fill in the suggested commit message in the box at the top.
Ctrl+# (Keybinding #2 & #3) -> Commits the message currently in the box, and returns focus either to:

the Integrated Terminal, if the shortcut was pressed while the focus (your text cursor) was in the terminal.
The Editor (the file currently open).




Simple and easy, if you are using Terminal in VSCode, you can use Ctrl+I to suggest it, make sure that your cursor is in terminal.


I'm using following version, if you don't see anything, please update to that corresponding.
 - Version: 1.245.1217
 - Build: nightly
 - Editor: vscode/1.95.3

Be noticed that Windows Terminal is not supported keyboard trigger like this yet.

I'm not sure this does what I was asking? I do also have the suggestion box appear with CTRL+I, but that does not have copilot write the commit message...
I've edited the question to show a GIF of the behaviour clicking the stars next to the commit message box adds.

@SWA I was confused with your mentioned Terminal suggestion. For shortcut, you can do by Ctrl + K + S, finding and binding GitHub Copilot: Generate Commit Message with Copilot, Git: Commit,... etc will solve your problem. No need to copy back to terminal.

Thanks for your help, the terminal was indeed the key requirement. I've added a solution which takes care of what I was looking for.
